# neo4j-javascript-driver - socket ended by other party

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

We've recently started using the javascript neo4j-javascript-driver v1.0.4 (and tried 1.1.0-m02) in a node/express app running on Heroku and we're finding that we get occasional *'This socket has been ended by the other party'* errors. Roughly about 2 errors per hour for an API handling around 15 requests/minute.

We're running node v4.6.1 and neo4j v 3.0.6 community edition on GrapheneDB.

The error reported is:

```
1    at TLSSocket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js line 284 col 12)
2    at NodeChannel.write (/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js line 329 col 20)
this._conn.write(buffer._buffer);
3    at Chunker.flush (/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/chunking.js line 114 col 18)
this._ch.write(out.getSlice(0, out.position));
4    at Connection.sync (/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js line 489 col 21)
this._chunker.flush();
5    at Session.run (/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/session.js line 102 col 20)
this._conn.sync();
6    at Order.updateAllRights (/app/models/order.js line 300 col 13)
dbSession.run(query, queryParams)
7    at <unknown> (/app/handlers/webhooks/chargify.js line 529 col 28)
return context.order.updateAllRights();
8    at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js line 26 col 23)
return target.apply(this, arguments);
9    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js line 510 col 31)
x = tryCatch(handler).call(receiver, value);
10    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js line 584 col 18)
this._settlePromiseFromHandler(handler, receiver, value, promise);
11    at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js line 128 col 12)
fn.call(receiver, arg);
12    at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js line 133 col 10)
this._drainQueue(this._normalQueue);
13    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js line 15 col 14)
self._drainQueues();
14    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js line 383 col 17)
```

I'm trying to work out if there's anything I can do to resolve this or whether I need to switch back to a REST type driver.

Reported in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/144 but no responses there so far.

Comment: after inspecting my code, I suspect that I may sometimes be committing my transaction before all the queries in the tx have completed (I misunderstood how transactions worked). I'm hoping that this was the cause of the errors - I'll update here once I've updated my code and verified.

Comment: no further errors since I refactored the transaction. It's looking highly likely that committing the transaction before all queries in the transaction had completed was the source of this error.